# Finding the next element containing a string

Tags: jquery

I want to implement a search feature for divs.  I want to search for a div, find it, and with the same string find the next div containing that string.  I have this to do the search.

```
               search_select = ':containsi("'+search_str+'")';
               result = $('#'+card_id).next(search_select);
```

But the next function doesn't seem to like the :contains selector.  Here is the function that performs the search.

```
      var linkcard_search_string = null;
      var last_search_card_id = null;
      function find_linkcard() {
            var search_str = prompt("Enter search string to find LinkCard:",linkcard_search_string);
            var search_select ='';
            var result;
            var card_id = last_search_card_id;
            if (card_id == null) {
               search_select = '.linkcard_header:containsi("'+search_str+'")';
               result = $(search_select);
            }
            else { 
               search_select = ':containsi("'+search_str+'")';
               result = $('#'+card_id).next(search_select);
            }
            if (result.length == 0 || result.length == null) { 
               alert('No LinkCard found containing that string.'); 
               return;
            }
            card_id = result.first().parent().attr('id');

            // Scroll LinkCard into view
            linkcard_top = $('#'+card_id).position().top+40;
            $('#'+card_id).effect("pulsate", { times:4 }, 500);
            $('#'+card_id).show('highlight',{color: 'lightcyan'},'slow');
            $('#'+card_id).addClass('highlight_linkcard');
            $('#matting').scrollTop(linkcard_top);

            last_search_card_id = card_id;
            linkcard_search_string = search_str;
      }
```

Is there a better way to search for the next element containing a string starting from a given element?

UPDATE

There were a lot of good suggestions to do the search.  What I have now is this.

```
       search_select = ':containsi("'+search_str+'")';
       result = $('#'+card_id).nextAll(search_select).eq(0);
       card_id = result.attr('id');
```

This works and allows me to find the divs containing the search string.  The problem is that the search looks in the entire div: header and contents.  I would like to search only an element of a specific class to restrict the search to the div header.  Something like this.

```
       search_select = '.linkcard_header:containsi("'+search_str+'")';
       result = $('#'+card_id).nextAll(search_select).eq(0);
       card_id = result.attr('id');
```

to search only the part of the div with class .linkcard_header.  I only want to search the header for the div and not the contents.  But that breaks the search.  How do I make nextAll() look at a specific class within the div?

Comment: `next()` only gets the element directly next to the element (if it matches), try using `nextAll()`.  Also `:containsi` is not a selector, it's `:contains`.

Comment: It looks like you have a spelling error on "contains".  Your selector is ":containsi" instead of ":contains".

Comment: like Rocket said, use nextAll(), and then .eq(0) to just get the first one.

Comment: Are you using `:containsi` from this post: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/278?

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for all the responses.  I have a extended contains to be case insensitive.  The suggestion to use nextAll() with the search_select with .eq(0) seems the right one.  The only problem now is that contains searches the entire div.  I only want to search an element of a specific class called .linkcard_header.  I have updated the question to show what I have now, what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question combines the suggestions from IAbstractDownvoteFactory, Rocket, and Maxedison.  To get the linkcard I needed nextAll(), find() and eq(0).  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I ended with this.

```
       search_select = '.linkcard_header:containsi("'+search_str+'")';
       result = $('#'+card_id).nextAll().find(search_select).eq(0);
       card_id = result.parent().attr('id');
```

Here is the complete function.

```
    var linkcard_search_string = null;   
    var last_search_card_id = null;   
    function find_linkcard() {
            var search_str = prompt("Enter search string to find LinkCard:",linkcard_search_string);
            var search_select ='';
            var result;
            var card_id = last_search_card_id;
            if (card_id == null) {
               search_select = '.linkcard_header:containsi("'+search_str+'")';
               result = $(search_select);
               card_id = result.first().parent().attr('id');
            }
            else { 
               search_select = '.linkcard_header:containsi("'+search_str+'")';
               result = $('#'+card_id).nextAll().find(search_select).eq(0);
               card_id = result.parent().attr('id');
            }
            if (result.length == 0 || result.length == null) { 
               alert('No LinkCard found containing that string.'); 
               return;
            }

            // Scroll LinkCard into view
            linkcard_top = $('#'+card_id).position().top+40;
            $('#'+card_id).effect("pulsate", { times:4 }, 500);
            $('#'+card_id).show('highlight',{color: 'lightcyan'},'slow');
            $('#'+card_id).addClass('highlight_linkcard');
            $('#matting').scrollTop(linkcard_top);

            last_search_card_id = card_id;
            linkcard_search_string = search_str;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use find, next simply returns the next element in the DOM:

```
<li class="one">one</li>
<li>next</li>
<script>
    $('.one').next(); // is [<li>next</li>]
</script>
```

but find will return an array of matching objects:

```
search_select = ':contains('+search_str+')';
result = $('#'+card_id).find(search_select);
result[0]; // first div
result[1]; // second div
```

Comment: If I get an array of matching objects, I will have to place the card id in that array and then look for the divs that come after it.  I prefer a method that systematically returns the div that comes after the one specified.

Answer (score 0):

The main challenge you have is that `next()` or even `nextAll()` will only work for siblings of the current element (the former will only check the next sibling, the latter will check all siblings that come after it). If you know that the search results you want found will always be siblings of the current result, then that's fine. But if that isn't the case, then I'd recommend doing the following. In fact, you might want to simply do this anyway:

```
var search_select = ':contains("'+search_str+'")';
var allResults = $(search_select);
```

Just get all the results at once. Then do your highlighting, pulsating, etc to the first of the found results (`allResults.eq(0)`). Subsequent "find next result" actions would just increment a counter somewhere and use that counter to do `allResults.eq(i)` (where `i` is the counter).

Comment: The search results should always be siblings of the current div. So nextAll() works in the way mentioned in the update.  This seems to be a good approach.  I must fine tune the nextAll() selector to search only an element within the div, i.e. the header.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#'+card_id).siblings(':containsi("'+search_str+'"):first');
```